# В чем отличие IP адресов

Tags: сеть, ip

В чем отличие адресов `127.0.0.0` `127.0.0.1` `192.168.0.1` `localhost` и `0.0.0.0`?

Comment: localhost это альяс вроде бы. Не ip адрес. 127 и 192 отличаются размером сети. 127 это обычно ты и твой роутер, 192 уже побольше) четыре нуля -шлюз по умолчанию. Через него идёт все на что нету правила. Ответ сугубо на пальцах поэтому в комментарии, ждём полноценного.

Comment: подсеть 127.0.0.0/8 используется только в пределах одного компьютера, обычно не маршрутизируется ни в каких сетях. 192.168.0.0/16 подсеть (наряду с 10 и 172) для локального использования в пределах одной частной сети, но не в интернете

Comment: так же хотелось бы дополнить комментарий Mike диапазоном приватных адресов 100.64.0.0/10 которые предполагается использовать в CGN наравне с 10, 172, 168 и это регламентируется RFC 6598, но почему-то все на них поклали хер и из-за этого где-то плачет один сетевой администратор :'(

Comment: спасибо большое всем, но я еще не очень разбираюсь во всем этом и немного не понял ответов выше, извините. Буду разбираться дальше.

Comment: @Mike Поправка: 192.168.0.0/16 - это 256 разных сетей :-)

Comment: @PavelMayorov Ну как диапазон на сети побить это каждый сам решает, времена когда не было сетевых масок и использовались только классы ABCD уже давно прошли :) может я применю маску /30 и получу 16384 сети ;)

Answer (score 1):

По умолчанию адреса подсети **127.0.0.0** c маской **255.0.0.0** назначены самому компьютеру. Сделано это для возможности общения между собой внутренних программ через протоколы TCP.

**localhost** - по умолчанию алиас **127.0.0.1** - (смотрим файл *C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts* - Windows или */etc/hosts* в Linux )

Адрес **0.0.0.0**, означает **все адреса**, и рассматривается обычно в контексте маршрутизации. (команды Windows - **route print** или Linux - **route**). Первая строка в таблице означает "все, что не встретилось в виде явного маршрута ниже, отправлять на шлюз с адресом **192.168.1.1** через сетевую карту **192.168.1.150**"

Пример

```
  Активные маршруты:
  Сетевой адрес     Маска сети      Адрес шлюза       Интерфейс  Метрика
      0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0      192.168.1.1    192.168.1.150     50
    127.0.0.0        255.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
    127.0.0.1  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
    127.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
```

Comment: Вот как раз в таблице маршрутизации у 0.0.0.0 нет никакого специального значения, маршрут по умолчанию вполне укладывается в правила маршрутизации.

Comment: А вот где специальное значение есть - так это при привязке сокетов, тут 0.0.0.0 означает "все интерфейсы".

Comment: про сокеты писать не стал, так как ответы в стиле overcvalified не проясняют вопрос, а только запутывают новичка.